# Receive signal in newly added listview entry

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to execute a function in a newly added entry to my ListView.
After adding an entry via button I want to execute the just added delegate's onNewEntry function. But only the old delegates execute it.

Minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
id:root
width: 640
height: 480
visible: true
signal newEntry(int new_row)
property var someProperty
ListModel {
    id:listmodel
    ListElement {
        name: "Bill Smith"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "John Brown"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Sam Wise"
    }
}

ListView{
    id: listView
    width:100
    height:200
    model: listmodel
    delegate: ItemDelegate{
        id:delegateId
        Text{
        text:name
        }
        Connections { //ISSUE!!!: the new delegate doesnt execute this, just the old ones
            target: root
            function onNewEntry(new_row){
                console.debug(index)
                console.debug(new_row)
                if(new_row==index){ //doesnt get true
                    listView.currentIndex = index
                    setProductData()
                }
            function setProductData(){
                root.someProperty=name
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
Button {
    anchors.top: listView.bottom
    id: btnAdd
    text:"+"
    onClicked:{
        listmodel.append({"name":"Joe Black"})
        newEntry(listView.count-1) //emit signal newEntry
    }
}
}
```

output:
qml: 0
qml: 3
qml: 1
qml: 3
qml: 2
qml: 3

My already mentioned workaround is using ListView.onAdd in the delegate:

```
delegate: ItemDelegate{
    ListView.onAdd: {
        setProductData()
    }
```

My question is: Why does the newly added entry doesnt listen to the newEntry signal. Thank you

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: It seems possible that the `newEntry` signal would get emitted before the new `ItemDelegate` has been fully constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better, probably more efficient solution:

```
delegate: ItemDelegate{
    ListView.onAdd: {
        listView.currentIndex=index
        setProductData()
    }
```

only the newly added delegate receives onAdd not all, like in the approach before.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to just set the `currentIndex` after inserting the new row:

```
Button {
    id: btnAdd
    onClicked: {
        sqlTableModel.insertNewEmptyRow()
        listView.currentIndex = listView.count - 1
    }        
}
```

Comment: and how will delegates function setProductData() be executed?

Comment: I didn't address that because you didn't provide the code for it in your original question. Now that you've edited it, it's still not something I can run myself to make any sense of it.